# How to customize the camera view and capture the part in the overlay?

Tags: ios, swift, camera, uiimage, avfoundation

I need to build a custom camera view similar to this: [example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJ73a.jpg)

I've used AVFoundation and placed an UIImageView over the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer and it look almost the same (although I'm not sure if this is the right way, thats way I wrote the title like this). I'm capturing the image and saving it to the gallery, but I need only the image in the rectangle in the middle.

Any suggestions how to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the answer from Nishant Bhindi needs some corrections. The code below will do the work:

```
func cropToBounds(image: UIImage) -> UIImage
{
    let contextImage: UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: image.cgImage!)
    let contextSize: CGSize = contextImage.size
    let widthRatio = contextSize.height/UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
    let heightRatio = contextSize.width/UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width

    let width = (self.imgOverlay?.frame.size.width)!*widthRatio
    let height = (self.imgOverlay?.frame.size.height)!*heightRatio
    let x = (contextSize.width/2) - width/2
    let y = (contextSize.height/2) - height/2
    let rect = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)

    let imageRef: CGImage = contextImage.cgImage!.cropping(to: rect)!
    let image: UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef, scale: 0, orientation: image.imageOrientation)
    return image
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to crop the image in context of overlay imageView.Pass the captured image in below function that may help you.

```
func cropToBounds(image: UIImage) -> UIImage
{
        let contextImage: UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: image.cgImage!)
        let contextSize: CGSize = contextImage.size
        let widthRatio = contextSize.height/UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
        let heightRatio = contextSize.width/UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height

        let width = (self.imgOverlay?.frame.size.width)!*widthRatio
        let height = (self.imgOverlay?.frame.size.height)!*heightRatio
        let x = ((self.imgOverlay?.frame.origin.x)!)*widthRatio
        let y = (self.imgOverlay?.frame.origin.y)!*heightRatio
        let rect = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: height, height: width)

        let imageRef: CGImage = contextImage.cgImage!.cropping(to: rect)!
        let image: UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef, scale: image.scale, orientation: image.imageOrientation)
        return image
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!...The issue is that it returns the top left corner of the image...not the image in the overlay borders...and the quality is bad :(

Comment: add that overlay image view in your preview view.